# Function arguments in another Function if importing is required

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found this script on stackoverflow which helps me to pass arguments from one function to another:

```
def perform( fun, fun2, *args ):
  fun(*args)
  fun2(*args)

def action1(filename, destination):
  print filename, destination

def action2(filename, destination):
  print 'help me find my {}'.format(filename)
  print 'it is located at {}'.format(destination)

perform(action1, action2, 'text.csv','/User/username/Desktop')
```

Results in:

```
text.csv /User/username/Desktop
help me find my text.csv
it is located at /User/username/Desktop
```

But... what if `action1` or `action2` is in another python .py file? I could import them, but unsure of how to make it behave the same way as above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "how to make it behave same way as above"? In this simple case importing the function from another module doesn't really affect anything.

Comment: The functions only use data which is passed to them, so if they are in the same file or not is irrelevant.

Comment: I think a lightbulb just switched. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

`from usermodule1 import action1, action2`

 `from usermodule2 import perform`

`perform(action1, action2)`

```
usermodule1.py - .py file with defined action1, action2 functions
usermodule2.py - .py file with defined perform funtion
```